# Google maps JavaScript API のDos攻撃対策について

Tags: javascript, google-maps, security

Github pages 上でGoogle maps JavaScript APIを使ったアプリを作成しようと考えています。
このAPIは使用制限があり、料金は下記のようになっています。

> マップのロードが 90 日間連続して 1 日 25,000 回を超過するまで無料 マップのロードが 90 日間の 1 日あたりの
>   25,000 回の使用制限に達した場合、1 日 25,000 回の超過分に対し 1,000 回ごとに $0.50 USD を課金、最大で 1
>   日あたり 1,000,000 回まで

Dos攻撃を受けた場合この制限を超えて自動的に課金が発生してしまいます。そこで対策をしたいですが、JavaScriptのみでDos攻撃の対策をすることは可能なのでしょうか。

Comment: 課金は強制ではなく、超過した時にAPIを停止するか課金を発生させるかは選択できます。